# How to plot clusters and centers from a multi-feature kmeans model, with Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I used `kmeans` algorithm to determine number of clusters in my dataset. In the following code, you can see that I have multiple features, some are categorical some are not. I encoded, and scaled them, and I get my optimal number of clusters.

You can download data from here:
https://www.sendspace.com/file/1cnbji

```
import sklearn.metrics as sm

from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

from sklearn.preprocessing import Normalizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, SpectralClustering, MiniBatchKMeans
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd



df = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
print(df.columns)

features = df[['parcela', 'bruto', 'neto',
               'osnova', 'sipovi', 'nadzemno',
               'podzemno', 'tavanica', 'fasada']]

trans = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('onehot', OneHotEncoder(), ['tavanica', 'fasada']),
                                        ('StandardScaler', Normalizer(), ['parcela', 'bruto', 'neto', 'osnova', 'nadzemno', 'podzemno', 'sipovi'])],
                          remainder='passthrough') # Default is to drop untransformed columns

features = trans.fit_transform(features)

Sum_of_squared_distances = []
for i in range(1,19):

     kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', random_state = 0)
     kmeans.fit(features)
     Sum_of_squared_distances.append(kmeans.inertia_)


plt.plot(range(1,19), Sum_of_squared_distances, 'bx-')
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('Sum_of_squared_distances')
plt.title('Elbow Method For Optimal k')
plt.show()
```

[image]

- On the graph, the elbow method shows my optimal number of clusters as 7.
- How can I plot the 7 clusters?

  - I want to see centroids on the graph, and scatter plot with 7 different colors of the clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Given [Plot: kmeans clustering centroid](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/kmeans-clustering-centroid/), where `centers` is one dimension. The `centers` array has a `(3, 2)` shape, with `x` as `(3, 1)` and `y` as `(3, 1)`.

  - The method demonstrated for this one dimension of centers, has been adapted to produce a solution for the seven dimensions of centers, produced by the model for this question.
- The `centers` returned for the model in this question has seven dimensions, with a shape of `(7, 14)` where `14` is 7 sets of `x` and `y` values.
- This solution answers the question, **How to plot the clusters & centers?**

  - It does not offer comments or interpretation on the results of the model, that would need to be a different question asked in [SE: Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or [SE: Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

```py
# uses the imports as shown in the question
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, Patch  # for creating a legend
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

# beginning with 
features = trans.fit_transform(features)

# create the model and fit it to features
kmeans_model2 = KMeans(n_clusters=7, init='k-means++', random_state=0).fit(features)

# find the centers; there are 7
centers = np.array(kmeans_model2.cluster_centers_)

# unique markers for the labels
markers = ['o', 'v', 's', '*', 'p', 'd', 'h']

# get the model labels
labels = kmeans_model2.labels_
labels_unique = set(labels)

# unique colors for each label
colors = sns.color_palette('husl', n_colors=len(labels_unique))

# color map with labels and colors
cmap = dict(zip(labels_unique, colors))

# plot
# iterate through each group of 2 centers
for j in range(0, len(centers)*2, 2):
    plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
    
    x_features = features[:, j]
    y_features = features[:, j+1]
    x_centers = centers[:, j]
    y_centers = centers[:, j+1]
    
    # add the data for each label to the plot
    for i, l in enumerate(labels):
#         print(f'Label: {l}')  # uncomment as needed
#         print(f'feature x coordinates for label:\n{x_features[i]}')  # uncomment as needed
#         print(f'feature y coordinates for label:\n{y_features[i]}')  # uncomment as needed
        plt.plot(x_features[i], y_features[i], color=colors[l], marker=markers[l], alpha=0.5)

    # print values for given plot, rounded for easier interpretation; all 4 can be commented out
    print(f'feature labels:\n{list(labels)}')
    print(f'x_features:\n{list(map(lambda x: round(x, 3), x_features))}')
    print(f'y_features:\n{list(map(lambda x: round(x, 3), y_features))}')
    print(f'x_centers:\n{list(map(lambda x: round(x, 3), x_centers))}')
    print(f'y_centers:\n{list(map(lambda x: round(x, 3), y_centers))}')
    
    # add the centers
    # this loop is to color the center marker to correspond to the color of the corresponding label.
    for k in range(len(centers)):  
        plt.scatter(x_centers[k], y_centers[k], marker="X", color=colors[k])
    
    # title
    plt.title(f'Features: Dimension {int(j/2)}')
    
    # create the rectangles for the legend
    patches = [Patch(color=v, label=k) for k, v in cmap.items()]
    # create centers marker for the legend
    black_x = Line2D([], [], color='k', marker='X', linestyle='None', label='centers', markersize=10)
    # add the legend
    plt.legend(title='Labels', handles=patches + [black_x], bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc='center left', borderaxespad=0, fontsize=15)
    
    plt.show()
```

### Output of plotting

- Many of the plotted features have overlapping values and centers.
- The `x` and `y` values for `features` and `centers` have been printed to more easily see the overlap, and to confirm the plotted values.

  - The responsible `print` lines can be commented out or removed, when no longer needed.

#### Feature 0

```py
feature labels:
[6, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6]
x_features:
[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
y_features:
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
x_centers:
[1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
y_centers:
[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 1.0]
```

[image]

#### Feature 1

```py
feature labels:
[6, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6]
x_features:
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
y_features:
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
x_centers:
[1.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
y_centers:
[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

[image]

#### Feature 2

```py
feature labels:
[6, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6]
x_features:
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
y_features:
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
x_centers:
[0.0, -0.0, 0.125, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
y_centers:
[0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
```

[image]

#### Feature 3

```py
feature labels:
[6, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6]
x_features:
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
y_features:
[0.298, 0.193, 0.18, 0.336, 0.181, 0.174, 0.197, 0.23, 0.175, 0.212, 0.196, 0.186, 0.2, 0.15, 0.141, 0.304, 0.108, 0.101, 0.304, 0.105, 0.459, 0.18, 0.16, 0.224, 0.216, 0.246, 0.139, 0.111, 0.227, 0.177, 0.159, 0.25, 0.298, 0.223, 0.335, 0.431, 0.17, 0.381, 0.255, 0.222, 0.296, 0.156, 0.202, 0.145, 0.195, 0.15, 0.141, 0.18, 0.336, 0.175, 0.212, 0.196, 0.186, 0.2, 0.15, 0.141, 0.177, 0.177, 0.177, 0.177, 0.177, 0.177, 0.224, 0.224, 0.18, 0.16, 0.222, 0.202, 0.18, 0.336]
x_centers:
[0.0, -0.0, 0.875, -0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
y_centers:
[0.196, 0.188, 0.249, 0.196, 0.237, 0.182, 0.328]
```

[image]

#### Feature 4

```py
feature labels:
[6, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6]
x_features:
[0.712, 0.741, 0.763, 0.704, 0.749, 0.741, 0.754, 0.735, 0.744, 0.738, 0.743, 0.747, 0.758, 0.759, 0.749, 0.714, 0.766, 0.748, 0.728, 0.755, 0.681, 0.752, 0.762, 0.734, 0.721, 0.747, 0.749, 0.756, 0.737, 0.748, 0.742, 0.724, 0.712, 0.733, 0.73, 0.688, 0.722, 0.705, 0.777, 0.749, 0.733, 0.744, 0.733, 0.764, 0.739, 0.76, 0.749, 0.763, 0.704, 0.744, 0.738, 0.743, 0.747, 0.758, 0.759, 0.749, 0.748, 0.748, 0.748, 0.748, 0.748, 0.748, 0.734, 0.734, 0.752, 0.762, 0.749, 0.733, 0.763, 0.704]
y_features:
[0.614, 0.636, 0.612, 0.601, 0.631, 0.64, 0.62, 0.624, 0.636, 0.633, 0.632, 0.63, 0.61, 0.629, 0.641, 0.616, 0.629, 0.65, 0.601, 0.644, 0.539, 0.628, 0.623, 0.627, 0.65, 0.603, 0.641, 0.641, 0.616, 0.632, 0.648, 0.631, 0.614, 0.624, 0.58, 0.562, 0.666, 0.587, 0.565, 0.616, 0.591, 0.646, 0.642, 0.625, 0.631, 0.629, 0.641, 0.612, 0.601, 0.636, 0.633, 0.632, 0.63, 0.61, 0.629, 0.641, 0.632, 0.632, 0.632, 0.632, 0.632, 0.632, 0.627, 0.627, 0.628, 0.623, 0.616, 0.642, 0.612, 0.601]
x_centers:
[0.745, 0.747, 0.73, 0.741, 0.735, 0.752, 0.708]
y_centers:
[0.63, 0.625, 0.611, 0.632, 0.62, 0.625, 0.604]
```

[image]

#### Feature 5

```py
feature labels:
[6, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6]
x_features:
[0.164, 0.096, 0.103, 0.171, 0.091, 0.106, 0.094, 0.132, 0.105, 0.098, 0.102, 0.101, 0.115, 0.079, 0.095, 0.135, 0.075, 0.088, 0.126, 0.063, 0.186, 0.088, 0.075, 0.134, 0.107, 0.134, 0.09, 0.072, 0.16, 0.097, 0.073, 0.123, 0.165, 0.154, 0.133, 0.158, 0.084, 0.11, 0.105, 0.1, 0.164, 0.075, 0.1, 0.075, 0.135, 0.069, 0.095, 0.103, 0.171, 0.105, 0.098, 0.102, 0.101, 0.115, 0.079, 0.095, 0.097, 0.097, 0.097, 0.097, 0.097, 0.097, 0.134, 0.134, 0.088, 0.075, 0.1, 0.1, 0.103, 0.171]
y_features:
[0.001, 0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.005, 0.002, 0.001, 0.002, 0.001, 0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.004, 0.004, 0.001, 0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.003, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.0, 0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.001]
x_centers:
[0.093, 0.1, 0.116, 0.112, 0.125, 0.101, 0.152]
y_centers:
[0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.001]
```

[image]

#### Feature 6

```py
feature labels:
[6, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 3, 4, 1, 0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 6]
x_features:
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.002, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
y_features:
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
x_centers:
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.001, 0.0]
y_centers:
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

[image]

### Update with all dimensions on one plot

- As requested by the OP

```py
# plot
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
for j in range(0, len(centers)*2, 2):
    
    x_features = features[:, j]
    y_features = features[:, j+1]
    x_centers = centers[:, j]
    y_centers = centers[:, j+1]
    
    # add the data for each label to the plot
    for i, l in enumerate(labels):
        plt.plot(x_features[i], y_features[i], marker=markers[int(j/2)], color=colors[int(j/2)], alpha=0.5)

    # add the centers
    for k in range(len(centers)):  
        plt.scatter(x_centers[k], y_centers[k], marker="X", color=colors[int(j/2)])

# create the rectangles for the legend
patches = [Patch(color=v, label=k) for k, v in cmap.items()]
# create centers marker for the legend
black_x = Line2D([], [], color='k', marker='X', linestyle='None', label='centers', markersize=10)
# add the legend
plt.legend(title='Labels', handles=patches + [black_x], bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 0.5), loc='center left', borderaxespad=0, fontsize=15)
    
plt.show()
```

- As noted with the individual plots, there's a lot of overlap.
  [image]